# Non-interactive points in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, qgis2web

I do have a point layer (data from a GeoJSON) and a polygon layer (also GeoJSON) in Leaflet. Both layers are created the same way and I made both layers "non-interactive". Unfortunately the point layer still reacts on the click-event on the point. The polygon layer is working just fine. Is this a bug or a feature?

Both layers are defined like this:

```
var layer = L.geoJson(json_data, {
            interactive: false
}).addTo(map);
```

My goal is to set the points to "non-clickable" aka non-interactive as well.
A working example is given here: https://codepen.io/butcher/pen/dBpWRP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem comes from different nature of point and polygon representation.

Polygon is represented by itself and when you set `interactive` option for polygon to `false`, it becomes noninteractive.

Point is represented by marker and when you set `interactive` option for point to `false`, attached default marker stays interactive. You have to use `pointToLayer` option for defining your own noninteractive marker, something like this:

```
function pointToLayer(point, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {interactive: false});
}
var layer_airports_0 = new L.geoJson(json_airports_0, {
    interactive:false,
    pointToLayer: pointToLayer
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: You don't need to set the layer to "interactive:false". The declaration at the marker level suits just well.

Comment: I know, it was just copy/paste of original code from codepen.